# "bash -c" on Windows 10 and command not working due to quotes

Tags: bash, cmd, windows-10, cmder

I need to split a *.zst file into multiple smaller *.gz files using a Bash command **that works** in Windows cmd (using cmder):

```
bash
```

Then when Linux mode runs:

```
unzstd --long=31 -c /mnt/c/file.zst | split -C 200000000 -d -a4 - file-chunk --filter='gzip > /mnt/c/$FILE.gz'
```

However I need to run it as part of a **cmd script**, so my solution is to use **bash -c** to run it from within Windows cmd :

```
(some cmd Windows based) 
& (bash -c "unzstd --long=31 -c /mnt/c/file.zst | split -C 200000000 -d -a4 - file-chunk --filter='gzip > /mnt/c/$FILE.gz'")
& (some cmd Windows based)
```

But this does not work : even if I don't get any error, an empty ".gz" file with no name is created in the folder and that's it.

I think something unexpected happens with the single / double quotes, but not sure what to do. I tried to escape them with 'backslashes \ ' but nothing worked.

Comment: I'd look into PowerShell instead of trying to do anything in Windows cmd/batch scripting

Comment: when you run `bash` then obviously the shell is now bash and not cmd anymore, so any bash commands work. OTOH when you run commands in cmd then they're parsed according to cmd rules

Comment: The most unusual fact for me is that you don't get any error message. What output do you get when you do from your Windows cmd line a `bash -c "echo test"` or `bash -c "foo bar baz"`? If you also don't get an error at least, your _bash_  command does not invoke a bash.

Comment: if you're trying to run this from a `.bat` or `.cmd` file you may stumble onto the fact that CMD natively doesn't support subshells/expressions